# Linq Paging using Skip and Take returning wrong result

Tags: c#, .net, linq, paging

```
var queryResultPage = eventsResults.Results
                .Skip(pageParameters.PageSize * pageParameters.CurrentPageNumber)
                .Take(pageParameters.PageSize).ToList();

var queryResultPage = eventsResults.Results.Skip(10* 1).Take(10).ToList();
```

Now if the number of objects in Results is `16` this Linq query is
returning only `6` result, where it should have returned `10`.

Comment: But should not it should return 10 if i am not wrong as the page size is 10

Comment: So, everything is right. `Skip` 10 from 16 and `take` 10, it must return 6 elements. **It can't return non existing 4 elements.**

Comment: `Take` gets up to the number.

Comment: Could you describe in plain words what subset of `eventsResults.Results` you actually want?

Comment: You start with 16 elements. You skip 10 of them, leaving 6. You then take *up to 10* of them... so you get 6. Basically everything is working in the way you *should* be expecting it to.

Comment: Ya right I have to use pageParameters.CurrentPageNumber - 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed My error -

```
  var queryResultPage = eventsResults.Results
                .Skip(pageParameters.PageSize * (pageParameters.CurrentPageNumber - 1))
                .Take(pageParameters.PageSize).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

`CurrentPageNumber` should be zero-based if its 1 based just use `(CurrentPageNumber - 1)`

Answer (score 3):

You have stated that you want to skip the first 10 records and then take 10 of the rest. If it only contains 16 you get only the remaining 6 since `16-10=6`.

Maybe you should initialize `pageParameters.CurrentPageNumber` with 0 instead of 1. Then you're skipping `10 * 0` records for the first page.

Answer (score 1):

If the value of `pageParameters.CurrentPageNumber` on your first page is 1, then it's skipping the first 10 results and returning only the remaining 6 elements

Answer (score 1):

In case you would like the last page to contain result set of maximum page length then you should first check if this is the last page and take the last `<PageSize>` number of results:

```
if (pageParameters.PageSize * pageParameters.CurrentPageNumber > eventsResults.Results.Count()
{
    var queryResultPage = eventsResults.Results.Reverse().Take(pageParameters.PageSize).Reverse();
}
else
{
    // do the paging same way you did before
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CurrentPageNumber should be zero-based

You start with 16 elements. You skip 10 of them, leaving 6. You then take up to 10 of them... so you get 6. Basically everything is working in the way you should be expecting it to